# Object doesn't support property or method 'getUploader' in applet in IE11

Tags: javascript, java, internet-explorer, applet

I am getting this error while uploading file through applet.
It was working fine on IE 8 and IE 9.

```html
<applet id="jumpLoaderApplet" 
code="jmaster.jumploader.app.JumpLoaderApplet.class" name="jumpLoaderApplet"
archive="jumploaderConnector/jumploader.jar" width="650" height="350"
                             mayscript>
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="ac_fireUploaderFileAdded" value="true"/>
<param name="ac_messagesZipUrl" value="jumploaderConnector/messages.zip"/>
<param name="uc_uploadUrl" value="multipleUploadFile.action" />
<param name="UploaderConfig.resumeCheckUrl" value="multipleUploadFile.action" />
<param name="uc_partitionLength" value="${systemProperty['JUMP_PARTITION_LENGTH'].propertyValue}" />
<param name="uc_maxLength" value="${systemProperty['JUMP_MAX_TOTAL_SIZE'].propertyValue}"/>
<param name="uc_maxFileLength" value="${systemProperty['JUMP_MAX_SINGLE_FILE_SIZE'].propertyValue}"/>
<param name="uc_directoriesEnabled" value="true" />
<param name="uc_zipDirectoriesOnAdd" value="true" />
<param name="uc_zipCompressionLevel" id="uc_zipCompressionLevel" value="${systemProperty['JUMP_COMPRESSION_RATIO'].propertyValue}" />
<param name="uc_preserveRelativePath" value="true" />
<param name="vc_lookAndFeel" value="system" />
```

### Code

```
function appletInitialized(applet)
{
    appletGlobal = applet;
}

function validateFiles()
    {
        console.log("res enter code here lut"+appletGlobal.getUploader().getFileCount()); 
    
    }
```

Comment: are java applets still a thing this millennium? can you check if `appletInitialized` is being called - there's no reference to that anywhere but the function definition

Comment: this function was called while initialization of file and also i am able to get applet object .but when i am calling applet method that time error occures

Comment: ok, so in `appletIntiialize` do `console.log(applet)` - can you see a `getUploader` property?

Comment: yes it is getting .please note that it was working on IE8 and IE9

Comment: so, you can see `getUploader` as a (first level) property when you `console.log(applet)` inside of `appletIntiialize` - how odd - does the console.log happen before your error?